# How do I publish an existing Visual Studio to an existing GitHub repository?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I'm trying to do the impossible:

I have an existing Visual Studio solution and I want to publish the code to an existing private GitHub repository (yes, I have write access).

Am I trying to do the impossible? A client created a blank private repository and I want to upload an existing Visual Studio solution to it. Is this not possible?

Comment: Why not just clone the empty repo?, and then put the content of the project in that folder, the do a commit and push.

Comment: Still no go. Is there a good alternative to GitHub? I copied and pasted the files over in Windows, did a sync, and the files till don't appear in the repository on GitHub.

Comment: But, git is the repo management, git hub is a service that uses git underneath, you should not have problems with that, did you copy, or clone the repo? you have to open your git bash and then do a git clone, then add the files, then do an add and a commit (here is where the files are added to your local repo), and then a push (to update the remote repo, github)

Comment: How do I do that (cloning)? I'm about to drop GitHub and find some other form of source control. Do I have to upload each and every file individually? What is the purpose of the GitHub plugin for Visual Studio?

Comment: No no no, first you have to understand, GitHub is not the source control, is git, GutHub is a product that uses git. Let me give a very quick description

Comment: Git is for decentralized repositories, normally you will have a master (the remote repo) and then the user or developers will clone this repo to their local machines, then, when they make changes they commit to their repos (remember, this repos are local, master is not updated), then the users can commit, make changes, with no affect others, when the changes are ready then you push your local repo to the master repo, were is available for all the users

Comment: So 1.- Install git from https://git-scm.com/downloads, 2.- open the git bash and call  the clone command of the git bash, 3.- make your changes, 4.- Commit changes, 5.- Push to git hub. If you have an ide is going to be more easy, or if you are using windows tortoisegit can help you

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/es-es/docs/git/tutorial/creatingrepo

Comment: If you are using VS good, i don not know exactly the interface, but if you are in windows, i really recommend you tortoisegit as a side tool, simpler and easier to use, also general and with less footprint that open VS (open VS to change a line and commit it, it is far easy in tortoise). To clone in tortoise: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-clone.html once that you have this clone folder, you can copy your VS project to this folder and use it as normal (will detect the repo automatically)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have cloned the repository then copied my changed code to the cloned repository. Still, GitHub absolutely REFUSES to let me push any changes to it.

Comment: And suddenly I can finally push my changes to GitHub.